# Updating Openssh on ubuntu fails

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, openssh

I have one EC2 (AWS Amazon) running with Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Trying to update Openssh from 6.6p to 6.9, the only way is compile the source from the origin (openssh.com) because the Canonical not offers the newest version, even in the backports.

But, after to compile the code, using the tradicional method (.confiugre -- skipping the configure directory --, make and make install), I can not access my instance any more. Is displayed the error: Permission Denied (public key)

Sure, I still have the instance working because I did not close my session before to do the roll back, changing the new daemon (updated sshd file) by the old.

Anyway, I need to do this update. And, I'm here to ask for someone that can help me, how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

## **FIXED**

Fixed upgrading Ubuntu version, from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS (Xenial). This version have the OpenSSH 7.2. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: When you try to connect to the new `sshd`, try turning up the verbosity of the output with `ssh -v` (or even higher with `-vv` or `-vvv`), the output will show you what authentication methods are being tried and why.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for answer. I analyzed this by comparing the printed debug (-v) by two connections, both the new as the old to know where is the error. The two are exactly the same, with the exception, of course, for the daemon name.

Comment: If you still have an open ssh shell on the instance, try checking `/var/log/auth.log` for sshd errors.

Comment: Openssh "1:6.6p1-2" already contains some security fix. If you insist to compile the new sshd, why don't you do it in ANOTHER t2.small instance to weed out all possible issues.  For worst case, you may still mount the t2.small EBS root in another EC2 instance and inspect what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you all. But my time is running out. I solved the problem by upgrading the Ubuntu version. The Xenial has the newest version of Openssh.

Answer (score 0):

Install the new version of sshd with a target prefix directory of /usr/local

Alter the /usr/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config to use:

- "Port 2222" instead of 22
- "Loglevel DEBUG" instead of the default

Run /usr/local/sbin/sshd with -d flag

Connect to the host with an ssh client specificing port 2222 and the logging should give you some clues why it is broken, probably some permissions it doesn't like